# Override XHTML validation for Rich Text Fields in Sitecore

Tags: xsd, sitecore, xml-validation, sitecore6

I'm trying to embed some renderings as detailed in [this article](http://sitecorejohn.wordpress.com/2010/04/28/embed-renderings-maps-media-etc-in-sitecore-rich-text-editor-fields/). However when I try to add a rendering into a Rich Text field I get XHTML validation errors. I can't disable XHTML validation for the client so I wanted to extend the schema used for validation. This is stored in the /sitecore/shell/schemas directory.

The markup for the rendering I'm trying to embed is:

```
<smart:addresssnippet runat="server" />
```

I've tried to add a new schema for the smart namespace but this doesn't seem to work. When I go back to the HTML for the Rich Text field Sitecore has rewritten the code to be:

```
<smart:addresssnippet runat="server" xmlns:smart="http://www.sitecore.net/xhtml"></smart:addresssnippet>
```

This fails validation. Has anyone encountered this or a way to add renderings to the validation schema?

Comment: Can you specify which version of sitecore you are using?  The telerik radeditor has been upgraded in 6.4.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested adding the following xml on my local instance to sitecore\shell\Schemas\xhtml.xsd and it renders you tag as you wanted and does not have validation errors in the Rich Text Editor.

```
  <xs:element name="smart:addresssnippet">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would contact Sitecore support [here](https://support.sitecore.net/) (provided you have a login for it) or maybe you could also try [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum.aspx).